# Issue to loop for cicle

Tags: java, android, itext

with my code that i show you above, i get on the row items(see pics please) Name:1 Name:2 Name:3 while i want that this items stay on the same(first) column...
Who can help me?

[image]

```
PdfPCell cell;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Name"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantità"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("€"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
table.setHeaderRows(1);

for (int i=1;i<5;i++) {
    table.addCell("Name:" + i);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use colspan like so :

```
PdfPCell cell;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Name"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantità"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("€"));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(com.lowagie.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
table.setHeaderRows(1);

for (int i=1;i<5;i++) {
    // we add a cell with colspan 3
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name:" + i));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell(cell);
}
```

Comment: A colspan stretches the column as long as you want, there is also rowspan that strechws on row

Comment: Why are you still using `com.lowagie.text`? All iText packages with my name in the package name should no longer be used.